# What kind of votes count for the Where in the World hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Do only upvotes and downvotes on posts count for the Where in the World pair of hats? Or do other types of votes count, such as close votes, delete votes, etc.? The long description of the hat simply says "vote", and doesn't specify what kinds of votes count.

I just tested by casting a close vote on a site where I haven't earned the hat, and I didn't earn it. Is it because this type of vote is excluded, or is a bug that it's not awarded for close votes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only upvotes and downvotes on posts count towards the hat.

> the only vote types
> checked for by `Where in the World`
> are the ups and downs

Comment: I would upvote this answer, except that it's sort of a downer.

Answer (score 3):

Upvotes and downvotes all count. I upvoted stuff on MSE and SO and I got the hats there, whereas on ELL I downvoted, to test if it will give me the hat and it did.

I don't think close votes count since I asked Yaakov Ellis about the Cruse of Oil hat, I added in close votes and reopen votes to my request of proving a secret hat, but he said I wrote too many ways to get that Cruse of Oil hat, so I think it's the same for the Where in the World hat.

Anyway here is the transcript link for his message:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56475006#56475006

**Edited:**

Just saw Yaakov Ellis's answer, only UVs and DVs count.